# How can i change the content inside the <ul> so that it can match the current clicked button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, for-loop

i'm trying to change the content inside the `ul` so that it can match the current clicked `button` .

```
<div class="btns">
    <button class="active"></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</div>
<ul class="dynamiq_content">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
 </ul>

<script>
//variables 
     const ContentBtns = $(".btns button");
     const content = $(".dynamiq_content li");
//function 
    ContentBtns.on("click", function () {
          $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
          content.addClass("active");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Comment: for example: when I click the first button i want to show just the first <li class="active"></li>

Comment: and only the clicked has class active and the li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match buttons and `li` element so you can work with array.

Here is the snippet:

```js
//variables 
     var ContentBtns = $(".btns button");
     var content = $(".dynamiq_content li");
//function 
for(let i=0;i<=ContentBtns.length;i++){
ContentBtns.eq(i).on("click", function(){
  content.removeClass();
  ContentBtns.removeClass();
  ContentBtns.eq(i).addClass("active");
  content.eq(i).addClass("active");
});
}
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
    <button class="active">a</button>
    <button>b</button>
    <button>c</button>
</div>
<ul class="dynamiq_content">
    <li class="active">a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 ContentBtns.on("click", function () {
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
      var index = ContentBtns.index(this);
      content.removeClass("active").eq(index).addClass("active");


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content.addClass("active");
```

With this line you are adding the class to the active class to the ul element and not one of the li element below it.

If you add ids to both the buttons and list elements you can use them to identify which button was pressed. Afterwards you can then use it to select the same index of the list elements.

Something like:

```
 ContentBtns.on("click", function () {
          $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
          content.find("li")[pressedButtonIndex].addClass("active");
    });
```